# Mysql - how to sort results by values in columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two database tables `customers` which contains data about customers with the scheme like that:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM customers;

customer_id created_at              partner_id
1           "2019-08-20 09:17:58"   cats
2           "2019-09-12 11:46:37"   dogs
```

and `customers_facts` which keeps the customers facts in a form of `fact_name` and corresponding `fact_value`.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM customers_facts;

customer_id fact_name   fact_value
1           name        Milton
1           city        Milan
1           birthday    "2019-08-20 09:17:58"
1           company     Idaho
2           surname     Bloom
2           name        Orlando
3           name        Milton
3           city        Milan
3           birthday    "2011-10-20 11:17:58"
3           company     Chicago
```

I want to create a query to get all `customer_id` where `name=Milton` and `city=Milan` sorted by `birthday` and `company`. So in my example the results would be:

```
mysql> SELECT customer_id FROM ....

customer_id
1             
3
```

I have a query which gets all the `customers_id` where `name=Milton` and `city=Milan`

```
SELECT cf.* FROM customers_facts cf 
WHERE cf.customer_id IN (
SELECT cf.customer_id FROM customers_facts cf
WHERE (cf.fact_name,cf.fact_value) IN (('name','Milton'),('city','Milan'))
GROUP BY cf.customer_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
)
```

But I have no idea on how to sort the results by `fact_value` How to do it ? Is it even possible with such scheme ?

Comment: What is the exact output you want?  Do you want to see just matching IDs, or entire records?

Comment: Matching `customer_id` sorted

Comment: Can you change the database? Key/value tables are a nuisance to work with. Life will be much easier, if you just make name, company, birthday, and address columns in your customer table.

Comment: unfortunately not - that's why I am asking how to do it :C

Comment: I guess, if I were forced to work with this, I'd create a customer view containing all these rows turned into columns. That's an easy one-time task and from then on you can write very simple queries.

Comment: I don't think it ise a good idea - first of all I would need to constantly recreate the view whenever a new fact is put into the original table - secondly I couldn't have indexes so queries would be slow

Comment: Well, views work with the indexes of the underlying tables. So there should be no problem with this. Of course this is not as good as a real table containing these columns with the appropriate indexes, but you say you can't have that. As to new facts: Yes, whenever you are asked to write a query considering a new fact, you would have to update the view. When it's just about some unknown fact the query doesn't have to know, you would use the table instead...

Comment: ...This would represent a typical case for key/values: The base table (your view in this case) contains all columns the DBMS knows and works with, e.g. a name and a birthday. The key/value table would contain attributes only known to the user, not to the DBMS. So the user extends the table with their own attributes and can query them. Anyway, if you are fine with aggregations to get to the attributes, then why bother :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little tricky.  You can't filter easily *before* aggregating.  So, do the filtering in the `having` clause:

```
SELECT customer_id
FROM customers_facts
GROUP BY customer_id 
HAVING SUM( fact_name = 'name' AND fact_value = 'Milton' ) > 0 AND
       SUM( fact_name = 'city' AND fact_value = 'Milan' ) > 0
ORDER BY MAX(CASE WHEN fact_name = 'birthday' THEN fact_value END) DESC,
         MAX(CASE WHEN fact_name = 'company' THEN fact_value END)
```

Comment: how to change the order for each sorted value - I mean DESC,ASC - so for example I sort by birthday DESC + by company ASC - something like ORDER BY MAX(CASE WHEN fact_name = 'birthday' THEN fact_value END) DESC, ORDER BY MAX(CASE WHEN fact_name = 'company' THEN fact_value END) ASC but it's not working

Comment: @ClydeBarrow . . . You just add `ASC` and `DESC`.  The string values of the dates work for ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Ues pivoting logic to turn out the birthday for each matching customer group:

```
SELECT customer_id
FROM customers_facts
WHERE (fact_name, fact_value) IN (('name', 'Milton'), ('city', 'Milan'))
GROUP BY customer_id 
HAVING MIN(fact_name) <> MAX(fact_name)
ORDER BY MAX(CASE WHEN fact_name = 'birthday' THEN fact_value END);
```

Other than the `ORDER BY` clause, I used a `HAVING` clause which ensures that both the matching name and city were present in each matching customer group.

**Edit:**

Here is your desired `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY
    MAX(CASE WHEN fact_name = 'birthday' THEN fact_value END) DESC,
    MAX(CASE WHEN fact_name = 'company' THEN fact_value END);  -- ASC is default
```

Comment: no because I want it to be sorted by a `birthday` fact. In my example data in `customers_facts` there are two customers with facts `name=Milton` and `city=Milan` but I would like to sort them by fact `birthday` which they have different. Do you see what I mean ?

Comment: and how about when I would like to sort by multiple facts for example `birthday` and `company`?

Comment: To add a sorting level by company, you could add this: `MAX(CASE WHEN fact_name = 'company' THEN fact_value END)` ... basically, you can pivot out any value you want, per group.

Comment: and last question - how to change the order for each sorted value - I mean DESC,ASC - so for example I sort by `birthday` DESC  + by `company` ASC - something like `ORDER BY MAX(CASE WHEN fact_name = 'birthday' THEN fact_value END) DESC, ORDER BY MAX(CASE WHEN fact_name = 'company' THEN fact_value END) ASC` but it's not working

Comment: @ClydeBarrow You don't need to repeat `ORDER BY` for each sort condition.  Use the version at the bottom of my updated answer.

Comment: look here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e9972f/4/0 -- no matter whether I put DESC or ASC the results are the same